# How to obtain the Hardware information of the computer using Test Complete

Tags: testing, automated-tests, performance-testing, testcomplete

Right now I am working on the performance tests and I have come across the situation, where i need to obtain the hardware information of the computer on which tests are been performed. Is there any way to obtain the hardware information using JScript.

Thanks and Regards,

Guru...

Comment: Which exactly info? CPU name, memory size, number of monitors, etc? Please be specific.

Comment: Thank you Helen for the reply..... I am trying to obtain the information about the RAM & Processor installed on the Computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**  I have got the answer .....posting this as this might be useful for someone  else ......**

```
function RAM_Information()
{
var SystemAttributes = GetObject("winmgmts:");
var RAMSize = 0;
var MemoryPackets = SystemAttributes.ExecQuery("SELECT Capacity FROM  Win32_PhysicalMemory");

var enumItems = new Enumerator(MemoryPackets);
for ( ; !enumItems.atEnd(); enumItems.moveNext())
{
RAMSize += aqConvert.StrToFloat(enumItems.item().Capacity);
}

Log.Message("Total physical memory: " + VarToStr(RAMSize*0.000000001) + " GB");
return RAMSize*0.000000001;
}



function ProcessorInformation()
{
return Sys.CPU;
}
```